# OAuth, Scraping data - How to calculate device_id & device_token?

Tags: authentication, web-scraping, oauth

I'm trying to scrape olx.pl website. I want to get a phone number from advert. Example advert is here: https://www.olx.pl/d/oferta/mieszkanie-pokoj-do-wynajecia-CID3-IDG2hIu.html

You need to click: Zadzwoń / SMS to check phone number.

As you can see, the phone number is generate in two steps.

First is making request to: https://www.olx.pl/api/open/oauth/token/

This is POST request. Post params which is needed to make this request:

- client_id - this is into HTML source (CTRL+U in your browser)
- client_secret - this is into HTML source (CTRL+U in your browser)
- grant_type => 'device' (always the same value)
- scope => 'i2 read write v2' (always the same value)
- device_id - this param I need to calculate, but I don't know how
- device_token - this param I need to calculate, but I don't know how

Second step is making POST request for: https://www.olx.pl/api/v1/offers/621150874/limited-phones/

Here is using everything from FIRST STEP.

My question is: How I can calculate device_id and device_token for first request? Into HTML source these params not exist.

Comment: Got same issue. Did you found any solution for it?